# Google Firebase and Dagger-2 does not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, dagger-2, firebase-crash-reporting

I want to use Dagger2 and Firebase.
Unfortunately i'm getting the following error message:

> background_crash E/FA: Task exception on worker thread:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT]
>   doesn't exist.
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found.

If i do not use Dagger2 everything works fine.
Whats wrong here? Do i have to init the `FirebaseApp` manually? Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
// App extends Application
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
    firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
}
```

...

```
// AppComponent.class
@Provides
@Singleton
public FirebaseAuth provideFirebaseAuth() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
```

...

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface SignupComponent {
    void inject(SignupActivity signupActivity);
}
```

...

```
@Inject
public FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private SignupComponent signupComponent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    signupComponent = DaggerSignupComponent
            .builder()
            .appComponent(((App)getApplication()).getAppComponent())
            .build();
    signupComponent.inject(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.sign_up_btn_sign_up)
public void clickOnSignUp() {
    String email = emailInput.getText().toString();
    String pass = passwordInput.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "yeppppa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Aaaand my build file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you add "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'" in your app level build.gradle file ?

Comment: @KetanMehta yes i did. Please see my post. I added my build file.

Comment: Did you enable the sign in method in firebase console ? @Tobias

Comment: Yep. As i wrote. Everything works fine if i do not use Dagger. Without Dagger i can save, edit and delete my users.

Comment: Hey @tobias i have the same problem but i fixed the problem same as urs adding name to firebase, but now i have another problem that firebase should be generated any luck on ur side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually doesn't have anything to do with Dagger.  It has to do with a known issue with Firebase Crash Reporting alongside use of an Application subclass that deals with files or other resources that end up being shared between the main process and the process that Crash Reporting creates.  It's not often discussed that Android creates a new Application class for each process your app uses, and in your case, you effectively have two Dagger graphs that are conflicting with each other.

Read about the known problem at the end of this page:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android

The easiest solution would be to either remove the firebase-crash dependency, or move your init logic into a Content Provider instead of Application.  Use of Application is generally frowned upon by the Android platform team anyway.

You can also wait until Firebase Crash Reporting leaves beta, at which point it will no longer create a new process.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the crash dependency ( but now i'm getting the message `W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.`). I rebuilded the project, delete the build folder etc etc.. And yes, i know that the use of Application is not very nice but i did not find any other solutions.. every sample of "how to use Dagger" is using this Application class... ;)

Comment: That message is just a warning.  If you're not seeing anything behaving in correctly, you can ignore it.  An alternative to Application is a ContentProvider, as I mentioned in my answer.  They are only initialized in the main process, so it's safe to do init in there that can touch files without race conditions or unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 wrong configured dagger-compiler:

compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1'

please modify project level ' build.gradle:

buildscript 
{
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
And then app level build.gradle:

First, add plugin:

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

And then modify the dependency to

apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1"
```

Comment: I had done this bevor. My gradle script works fine. 
I get the same error.